# SocketIoClientDotNet with Visual Studio for mac can't install

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, socket.io, nuget

I am using Visual Studio for mac.
I tried to download SocketIoClientDotNet on nuget.
But I failed to install the package.

[MY SPEC]
Visual Studio Community 2017 for Mac
Version 7.1 (build 1297)
Runtime:
    Mono 5.2.0.215 (d15-3/da80840) (64-bit)
    GTK+ 2.24.23 (Raleigh theme)

Package version: 502000215

NuGet
버전: 4.3.0.2418

.NET Core
Runtime: Not installed
SDK: Not installed
MSBuild SDKs: /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.2.0/lib/mono/msbuild/15.0/bin/Sdks

Xamarin.Profiler
1.5.5
/Applications/Xamarin Profiler.app/Contents/MacOS/Xamarin Profiler

Apple Developer Tools
Xcode 8.3.3 (12175.1)
Build 8E3004b

Xamarin.Mac
Version: 3.6.0.19 (Visual Studio Community)

```
Attempting to gather dependency information for package 'SocketIoClientDotNet.0.9.13' with respect to project 'Chat', targeting '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile111'
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration3-gz-semver2/socketioclientdotnet/index.json
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration3-gz-semver2/socketioclientdotnet/index.json 1290ms
Total number of results gathered : 2
Gathering dependency information took 1.3 sec
Summary of time taken to gather dependencies per source :
https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json -   1.3 sec
Attempting to resolve dependencies for package 'SocketIoClientDotNet.0.9.13' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
Resolving dependency information took 0 ms
Resolving actions to install package 'SocketIoClientDotNet.0.9.13'
Resolved actions to install package 'SocketIoClientDotNet.0.9.13'
Retrieving package 'SocketIoClientDotNet 0.9.13' from 'nuget.org'.
For adding package 'SocketIoClientDotNet.0.9.13' to project 'Chat' that targets 'portable45-net45+win8+wpa81'.
Install failed. Rolling back...
Package 'SocketIoClientDotNet.0.9.13' does not exist in project 'Chat'
Package 'SocketIoClientDotNet.0.9.13' does not exist in folder '/Users/LSH/Work/Dev/WebServer/Chat/packages'
Executing nuget actions took 139.18 ms
Could not install package 'SocketIoClientDotNet 0.9.13'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile111', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
```

Answer (score 2):

The SocketIoClientDotNet 0.9.13 NuGet package has two portable assemblies:

```
lib/portable-win81+wpa81
lib/portable-wpa81+wp81
```

These do not map to any known Portable Class Library (PCL) profile so NuGet will not allow you to install it into a portable class library project.

The latest SocketIoClientDotNet beta version 1.0.2-beta1 has no PCL assemblies. Instead it has a .NET Standard 1.3 assembly. Unfortunately you cannot use that in a PCL project either.

So either you find another NuGet package that provides what you need and also supports PCL projects or you will have to modify your project to be a .NET Standard project that targets at least .NET Standard 1.3.